# WebView blank page after go to link

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

The app works fine but after you click the login link
The logon page does not appear, but the page remains blank

activity_main

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivty

```
//webview
    webframe.loadUrl(getString(R.string.Site_Link))
    webframe.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webframe.settings.allowFileAccess = true
    //Other WibView  Settings
    //End Other
    webframe.webViewClient = callurls()
    //Cach Settings
    webframe.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
    webframe.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
    webframe.settings.setAppCachePath("/data/data/$packageName/cache")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line

```
webframe.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

The dom storage is set to false by default, but it's needed for websites that uses HTML5 specifications.

An other problem could be the format of `Site_Link`.

So tell me what's the result.

Comment: same problem after add this code
am using kotlin ; and the same problem in java
the url is correct and i see the site working  after go to login page i see blank page

i have add this cod 
`webframe.settings.domStorageEnabled = true`


   `<string name="Site_Link">https://www.hsoub.com</string>`

Comment: when i go to account page in `https://www.hsoub.com`
in pc is working put in my app not working

Comment: Please try to change `webframe.loadUrl(getString(R.string.Site_Link))` position to the end and add this annotation to the onCreate method `@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")`

Comment: am using kotlin not java

Comment: `webframe.loadUrl(getString(R.string.Site_Link))
        webframe.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webframe.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        webframe.settings.domStorageEnabled = true`

Comment: It's the same annotation in kotlin, also just loadUrl after setting the settings

Comment: i have add the code but not working .
the same source in other site and is working
but in `https://accounts.hsoub.com/login`
i see only the background of the page

Comment: the same problem when i disable javascript in chroom

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your website isn't responsive, so it can't be fit in the mobile view.

Comment: the page using javascript . and webview not working in this page
and the same problem after enable javascript in webview